# Validate form using dynamically textarea name

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have one validation form using angular. I would like validate forms in `ng-repeat` using dynamically textarea name. Look on my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index">
  <form name="main.adminArticleReplyForm" novalidate>                                                   
    <div ng-class="{'has-success':(main.adminArticleReplyForm.commentReply_{{$index}}.$valid), 'has-error':(!main.adminArticleReplyForm.commentReply_{{$index}}.$valid)}"> 
      <textarea name="commentReply_{{$index}}" ng-model="main.commentReply[$index]" required></textarea>
      <ul ng-show="(!main.adminArticleReplyForm.commentReply_{{comment.number}}.$pristine && main.adminArticleReplyForm.$error.minlength[0].$viewValue.length)">
        <li>You have to add {{10 - main.adminArticleReplyForm.$error.minlength[0].$viewValue.length}} characters</li>   
      </ul>  
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And my problems:

1. If you check `{{main.adminArticleReplyForm}}` commentReply_{{$index}} is always last $index in ng-repeat for example if are 4 comments in array in form always is `commentReply_4`, but textareas name in `DOM` are correct.
2. I have to use controller as, in my case `main`, but if I remove `main` from form name, everything works nice.
3. Summary, `{{main.adminArticleReplyForm}}` is validate only for last $index in ng-repeat previously $indexes are ignored
4. Here is fiddle for look that every commentReply_{{$index}} is commentReply_2 https://jsfiddle.net/8od25zhb/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

1. you don't need to track it by `index` that make repeat last index
2. you don't need to add `main` to the `form`, because form is in repeat so make it unique, if you want to have just one form make it out of repeat; so we just use `comment.adminArticleReplyForm` as form name, and just `main.comments` used `main` from controller.
3. by this 2 step your forms validate just the textarea which inside it.
4. you don't need create unique names and models for textarea, because you create them inside `ng-repeat` and all are unique.

---

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as main">
    <div ng-repeat="comment in main.comments">
        <form name="comment.adminArticleReplyForm" novalidate>
            {{comment.adminArticleReplyForm}}
            <div>
                <textarea name="commentReply" ng-model="comment.commentReply" required></textarea>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr/>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, AngularJS default validation works on hierarchy of element names to detect their state thus, the name of `textarea` you have used is `commentReply_{{$index}}` with a underscore but you are using `commentReply{{comment.number}}` in the validation expressions. So make it look with a underscore and it will work. So, final code will look something like this:

```html
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index">
  <form name="main.adminArticleReplyForm" novalidate>                                                   
    <div ng-class="{'has-success':(main.adminArticleReplyForm.commentReply_{{$index}}.$valid), 'has-error':(!main.adminArticleReplyForm.commentReply_{{$index}}.$valid)}"> 
      <textarea name="commentReply_{{$index}}" ng-model="main.commentReply[$index]" required></textarea>
      <ul ng-show="(!main.adminArticleReplyForm.commentReply_{{comment.number}}.$pristine && main.adminArticleReplyForm.$error.minlength[0].$viewValue.length)">
        <li>You have to add {{10 - main.adminArticleReplyForm.$error.minlength[0].$viewValue.length}} characters</li>   
      </ul>  
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but this not solved my problem, look on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8od25zhb/5/ , here every commentReply_{{$index}} is commentReply_2

Comment: @Mat.Now `commentReply_{{$index}}` is `commentReply_2` because that is the recent value which it gets from the completion of `ng-repeat`. You have rendered `{{main.adminArticleReplyForm}}` which evaluates to different value in each ng-repeat loop. But it also keep updating it's value for each ng-repeat completion and displays the last value for ng-repeat item which is `commentReply_2 `. But if you inspect the element in browser console then the `ng-class` and `ng-show` expressions are correct.